# JMS Serializer - deserialize a non-recurrent node structure in xml

Tags: symfony, xml-deserialization, jmsserializerbundle

I use jms serializer bundle for deserializing xml into objects in my sf2 project. I didn't had any problem for creating all my models until I have to add this field :

```
<parent_property>
    <child_property_1>
        <![CDATA[ value ]]>
    </child_property_1>
    <child_property_1>
        <![CDATA[ value ]]>
    </child_property_1>
    <child_property_1>
        <![CDATA[ value ]]>
    </child_property_1>
    <child_property_2>
    <![CDATA[ value ]]>
    </child_property_2>
</parentProperty>
```

But this schema is not recurrent, the numbers of occurrences of child_property_1 or child_property_2 can change.

I tried many things (with the jms doc) but without success...

```
<?php
/**
 * @Serializer\XmlList(inline = true, entry = "child_property_1")
 * @Serializer\XmlList(inline = true, entry = "child_property_2")
 */
public $parentProperty;
?>
```

**EDIT :**

So I tried the Jakub Zalas's answer :

MainEntity.php

```
/**
 * @Serializer\Type("My\Bundle\Api\Model\ParentProperty")
 */
public $parentProperty;
```

ParentProperty.php

```
/** 
 * @Serializer\XmlRoot("parent_property")
 */
class ParentProperty
{
    /**
     * @Serializer\XmlList(inline = true, entry = "child_property_1")
     */
    $childProperty1;

    /**
     * @Serializer\XmlList(inline = true, entry = "child_property_2")
     */
    $childProperty2;
}
```

But the deserialization still failing. Moreover the process occurs in a command class so I don't have any error message... so it's quite difficult to debug

Comment: have you tried annotating two separate properties as opposed to a single one?

Comment: What do you mean ? I have to describe the parent property first, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added multiple mappings to a single property.

You should rather map each list to a separate property:

```
/** 
 * @XmlRoot("parent_property")
 */
class ParentProperty
{
    /**
     * @XmlList(inline = true, entry = "child_property_1")
     */
    $childProperty1;

    /**
     * @XmlList(inline = true, entry = "child_property_2")
     */
    $childProperty2;
}
```

See [the docs of JMSSerializer](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#xmllist).

Comment: Ok I get it, I'll test it tomorrow and I'll let you know :D

Comment: You'll need to provide an error message, or a full code example if you're not able to debug it yourself and still want to get help ;)

Comment: I added some snippet (in my question) for illustrating the current code used to serialize the properties I need. But i'll try to display an error message of course :) Thanks for your help

Comment: Ok I succeeded in displaying an error message and I had to precise a type for each child property : * @Serializer\Type("string") (for example).
The deserialization works well but the child properties values are not retrieved :/